# UIViewController gets stuck in horizontal orientation after portrait rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

View Controller A displays View Controller B in horizontal orientation

```
#pragma mark Rotation Delegate Methods
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return YES;
}

-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        [landscapeChartViewController.chartImageView reloadWithUrl:
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"someurl",[symbol uppercaseString]]];

        NSLog(@"showing chart");
        [self presentModalViewController:landscapeChartViewController animated:NO];
    }    
}
```

This works fine. View Controller B shows up in landscape orientation. Here is View Controller B's implementation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        NSLog(@"dismissing chart");
        [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I go back into portrait orientation to show View Controller A, View Controller A is stuck in landscape orientation. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: after reading your comment, I suggest trying to use `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` instead of `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`, like this:

controller A:

```
 - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
   if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
     [landscapeChartViewController.chartImageView reloadWithUrl:
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"someurl",[symbol uppercaseString]]];

     NSLog(@"showing chart");
     [self presentModalViewController:landscapeChartViewController animated:NO];
   }    
}
```

controller B:

```
 - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
  if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
      NSLog(@"dismissing chart");
      [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
  }
}
```

I do more or less the same in a project of mine, only between two non modal views.

Comment: You understand my problem correctly. Unfortunately, when I implement this code, View Controller B does not get dismissed when rotating to portrait mode.

Comment: That doesn't work properly either. View Controller B does not get dismissed when rotating to portrait mode.

Comment: have you put back in place your original `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` implementation, returning always YES?

Comment: Yes, I tried both scenarios where it always returns YES, and then your suggestion from your previous answer. Neither work.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to move your code from `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:` to `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` and use `self.interfaceOrientation` in place of `toInterfaceOrientation`.

Answer (score 0):

View Controller B shows up in landscape orientation. Here is View Controller B's implementation:

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
  {

  // Return YES for supported orientations
  return YES;

}

-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
    NSLog(@"dismissing chart");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the function willRotateToInterfaceOrientation? Also try using the Notification centre to notify the parent view controller that your modal view controller is rotated and then simply [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]

Answer (score 0):

I always write my orientation logic in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation.
Here is a part of my code it works fine....

```
 if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
         [connectCoverLockUnlockSwitch setFrame:CGRectMake(250,6,51,31)];
         UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

        if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation ==    UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){

            [connectCoverLockUnlockSwitch setFrame:CGRectMake(400,6,51,31)];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
        else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait){

        [connectCoverLockUnlockSwitch setFrame:CGRectMake(250,6,51,31)];
```

}
        }

```
    else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)     {
          UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];        

       if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationUnknown || orientation ==   UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp) {

//return;

  }
         if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation ==   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
              [connectCoverLockUnlockSwitch setFrame:CGRectMake(570,6,51,31)];

               [self.tableView reloadData];
       }

  else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || orientation ==   UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
       {
            [connectCoverLockUnlockSwitch setFrame:CGRectMake(330,6,51,31)];
            [self.tableView reloadData];

          }
          }
```